# Leaflet : How to move a Polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hi can i ask how to move the polygon in leaflet ? I have really no idea how to move it since i was using set `option {draggable : true }`.

> Give error : it is not a option.

```
    poly = new L.Polygon([coordinates],
        {   
            color: '#810541',
            fillColor: '#D462FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            // draggable: true
        }).addTo(map)
```

The output i wish to get is , i can move the polygons and see the coordinates of the polygons. 
Any help is appreciate !

Code Demo : 
https://jsfiddle.net/wesleylim97/wncy4mk5/6/

**Updates :** 
Problem is solved after added [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) plugin.

Include the script : 
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.path.drag@0.0.6/src/Path.Drag.min.js"></script>`

Working Demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/wesleylim97/wncy4mk5/13/

Thanks to @kboul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) plugin.

Include the script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.path.drag@0.0.6/src/Path.Drag.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.path.drag@0.0.6/src/Path.Drag.min.js"></script>




</head>

<body>



  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([3.1377736432253345, 101.56585693359375], 10);
    var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);



    var poly1 = [
      [
        [3.1377736432253345, 101.56585693359375],
        [2.929326028392636, 101.6619873046875],
        [3.03629758922721, 101.89544677734375],
        [3.247466393872138, 101.8048095703125]
      ]
    ]

    var polygon = new L.Polygon([poly1], {
      draggable: true,
      color: '#810541',
      fillColor: '#D462FF',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
    }).addTo(map);

    polygon.on('dragend', function(e) {
      console.log(e.target._latlngs[0][0]);
    });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wao .. You are awesome ! Thanks @kboul