# Leaflet - drag polygon with Leaflet.Path.Drag plugin

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm trying to drag a polygon in angular 13 empty project.
The code is exactly the same as here (accepted answer):
[Leaflet : How to move a Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966103/leaflet-how-to-move-a-polygon)

i put css and js files in angular.json but tried also inside index.html and polygon is just not draggable

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
          "./node_modules/@bopen/leaflet-area-selection/dist/index.css"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
          "./src/assets/Path.Drag.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly recommended this article how to integrate leaflet plugins to angular project. Many working examples are included and polygon drag is one of them.

https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-and-leaflet-plugins/

Basically need to add:

```
import 'leaflet-path-drag';
```